# How to display all records in query when using a criteria

Tags: database, ms-access

I have created a query and i have a field called Department. I have added a criteria to that field that allows user interface, when you run the query it asks for you to enter the department name you want to display. If I choose to display all departments records what can I put in to display all departments? I remember something about entering * to display all records but this does not want to work

Comment: It doesn't want to work, like it shouts out loud? where is your code and what errors are you getting...

Answer (score 1):

`*` only works with text fields and even then only when used with `LIKE` not `=`.

This is what I would use as filter:

```
[Department]=IIF([MyParameter]='',[Department],[MyParameter])
```

This should evaluate to always true when the Parameter is left empty.

Comment: This basically says if no parameter is entered, then compare field department to department which is like saying 1=1 so all records will always return.

Comment: I have entered the code into my query however it now tells me:
The specified field '[Department]' could refer to more than on table in the FROM clause of you SQL statement.

Comment: If you link two or more tables that both have the `Department` field you have to specify which table to use (even if we have the human knowledge that they should all be the same), Use this: `[MyTable].[Department]` instead of just `[Department]`.